# Is there any function available to echo current user's profile url?

Tags: users, author, profiles

As of now i'm using this code to echo user's profile url.

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>user/<?php echo $current_user->user_login ?>"><?php echo $current_user->user_login ?></a>
```

This link uses author base as "user". So when i change author base this link will be broken.

IS there any function available like `current_user_profile_link()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Choosing the right template

As your "User Profile"-Page is something completely custom and **not** the admin UI user profile page, I'd suggest to take the uthor posts page instead:

```
get_author_link( true, get_current_user_id() );
```

Then modify this template.

### Pretty URls

No need to go outside the WP template hierarchy. If you want something like `~/user`, then use the [`Rewrite API`](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api).

---

### ( Update )

`get_author_link()` This function has been deprecated. Use `get_author_posts_url()` instead.

**Example**

```
get_author_posts_url( get_current_user_id() );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url

Answer (score 0):

From Kaiser answer, get_author_link function is deprecated

> get_author_link is deprecated since version 2.1! Use get_author_posts_url() instead

So please try to use get_author_posts_url()